# How to update other dependent property on change of one property

Tags: c#, wpf, properties, inotifypropertychanged

Suppose in a C# WPF class I have something like this:

```
class test: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private datetime _DOB
    public datetime DOB 
    {
        get
        {
            return _DOB;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_DOB != value)
            {
                _DOB = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    private int _age
    public int Age 
    {
        get
        {
            return _age;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_age != value)
            {
                _age = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }
....

}
```

Now, let us suppose that a user can put in any of the properties. They can put in either their DOB, or their age, so making one of them calculated property would not work.

Apart from using methods like `UpdateAge()` in the setter of DOB and `UpdateDOB()` in the setter of Age, is there any other method that would automatically update the "dependent" properties along with the dependency properties (which INPC takes care of)?

Comment: That would certainly help in case of calculated properties, but not in my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is there any other method that would automatically update the "dependent" properties along with the dependency properties (which INPC takes care of)?

There is no "automatic" or magic here. You need to set the backing field and raise the PropertyChanged event for the data bound property that you want to refresh in the view.

Just make sure that you don't end up in an infinite loop where you set the `Age` property from the `DOB` property and vice versa.

You could set the _`age` backing field in the setter of the `DOB` property and vice versa, e.g.:

```
private DateTime _DOB;
public DateTime DOB
{
    get
    {
        return _DOB;
    }
    set
    {
        if (_DOB != value)
        {
            _DOB = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged();

            _age = DateTime.Now.Year - _DOB.Year;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Age");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "Just make sure that you don't end up in an infinite loop where you set the Age property from the DOB property and vice versa."

I hope `if (_DOB != value)` condition would take care of that. Am I wrong?

Comment: You are probably right assuming your calculations of the dates are correct :) Anyway, it's a good thing to keep this in mind which you apparently have done already.

Comment: Thank you. I wish there were some way to express dependency of one property on others, so that changing one's value would automatically trigger the re-evaluation of others.